# Adobe air android honeycomb/ics force close

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flash-media-server, forceclose

I have a video app (client a) that streams and receives audio via flash media server. It also does constant server side polling to maintain an engagement via an adobe air desktop app (client b) which does the same. The problem I'm having is that:
- 90% of the times when client b ends the engagement the app in client a force closes.
- 5% I have seen the app force close from when client a ends the engagement.
- works fine in gingerbread. Doesn't in honeycomb+

Debug doesn't throw anything, logcat throws an error that consumer closed the input...
I have isolated the problem to my flash media server class, however I am not doing anything different than any other connection class.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue? Like I said itworks fine in gingerbread...
Any pointers would be great.been banging my head against the wall for 2 weeks now and counting

Comment: list is not relevant to problem though ,but still http://www.slashgear.com/adobe-no-jelly-bean-flash-flash-player-pulled-altogether-august-15-29236404/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while to find the issue but in the end it was an issue in the fms server. 
I was running a function at an interval to check for user timestamps among other things, however when the engagement was being finished by client  b, the timestamp was stillt rying to run and disconnect a user, even though the connection was already closed.
Once I got that sorted the issue went away.

It is still weird how this issue wasnt affecting android 2.x devices...

This is probably not going to be very helpful to many people, however if you do see your app force closing, and one of the last messages your app receives is down to the fms, have a check for something your doing in the .asc file in your fms.

Unfortunately learnt this the hard way, spent 3 weeks looking at my code, thinking it was something it was doing or some kind of bug...
Glad I was wrong!